# Error in C# Microsoft.SqlServer reference

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, reference

If you look at the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXj2g.jpg) the reference have been done but it still gives error why is it so.

[image]

Comment: check the project framework, Is it client profile?

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your screenshot, i am certain that your project framework is set to client profile. change it to .Net Framework  4. and all will be fine. You can set it like

```
right click your project-->properties-->Application-->Target framework
```

set it to  **.Net Framework 4** instead of **.Net Framework 4 client profile**

Comment: i dont have the option as .Net Framework I have the options as .Net Framework 2.0, .Net Framework 3.0, .Net Framework 3.5, .Net Framework 3.5 client profile, .Net Framework 4,.Net Framework 4 client profile

Comment: @user2588812 assign .Net Framework 4. what is currently selected?

Comment: Error 2 One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: Have you also tried to reference this assembly --> Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll